# I need help Understanding Maximum profit

Tags: calculus

Josh has a cell phone repair business. The business has a $175$ monthly limit on the number of phones they can repair due to the lack of employees. HE currently charges $\$ 75$ Per Repair, But He Wants To Increase The Price Because Of The Positive Feedback He Has Received. He Estimates That For Each $\$ 5$ increase in price, $10$ fewer people will attend because the cell phone repair shop in the next town over is cheaper. What price will maximize Josh's profit?shop in the next town over is cheaper. What price will maximize Josh's profit?
This is what I have so far:
$(75+5x)(175-10x)-10(175-5x)$
The question I have is why do I multiply $175-5x$ by $10$ when I do the subtraction?

Comment: We use dollar signs to set of $\LaTeX$ for math formatting.  If you want dollar signs, you should use \$ to avoid problems.  Otherwise, just remove the dollar signs-it doesn't matter the currency.

Comment: \$ to use the dollar sign as the dollar sign :D $\$ 5 $. I edited it

Comment: Is 175 also there present number of repairs?

Comment: 175 is the max number of repairs

Comment: To get a dollar sign, you use backslash dollar sign.  Albanian_EAGLE and I tried to show that, but the backslash disappeared, so it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be explicit in defining the variables.  You are considering $x$ is the number of \$5 increments of price. Your expression $(75+5x)(175-10x)$ is a good expression for revenue as the price is increased assuming that the shop is busy today and there is not "pent up demand" that will come to replace the customers that leave if there is room.  Under that assumption I don't understand why you subtract $10(175-10x)$.  If $x=0$ that would have us subtracting some revenue, but we shouldn't because the price hasn't changed.  So I think the problem isn't the factor $10$ but the whole term.

Comment: So what do you suggest? I have to create my own problem then solve for the maximum profit, but I'm finding it very hard. What should i add or take away?

Comment: @user73316:  I am suggesting you delete the last term and maximize $(75+5x)(175-10x)$  This presumes the costs are fixed, so there is no reduction in profit caused by fixing fewer phones.  But if there are $10$ more customers who are currently being turned away because the shop can't handle them (and will pay any price because of convenience) it would be $(75+5x)(185-10x)$ as soon as $x \ge 2$.  This shows why business is harder than math.  Maybe your model is wrong.